# How to print a boolean value?

Tags: java, printing, boolean

I am trying to print out the boolean value, but it does not seem to work (I get an "unreachable statement" error and "missing return statement").

Here is my code:

```
public class DnaTest {
  public static void main(String[] args){
  aGoodBase('A');
 }

  public static boolean aGoodBase (char c) {                
    char [] charArray = { 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T' };
    boolean aBase;

    if (c == 'A' || c == 'G' || c == 'C' || c == 'T') 
    {
      return true;     
    } 
    else 
    {
      return false;
    }
    System.out.println(aBase);
  }  
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: You should specify what language that is. Maybe some java dialect?

Comment: `System.out.println(aBase);` looks unreachable, all code paths will hit a `return` before this line.

Comment: Even without knowing what language that is I can say that the issue with the "unreachable code" is the `println` statement: Your conditional right before it will _always_ return either with true or with false. You will _never_ reach the `println` statement.

Comment: You will never reach the print statement since you return either `true` or `false` before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you missed the return statement at the bottom. In fact, you can write this:

```
public static boolean aGoodBase (char c) {                
    char [] charArray = { 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T' };
    boolean aBase;

    if (c == 'A' || c == 'G' || c == 'C' || c == 'T') 
    {
      aBase = true;     
    } 
    else 
    {
      aBase = false;
    }
    System.out.println(aBase);
    return aBase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DnaTest {
  public static void main(String[] args){
  aGoodBase('A');
 }

  public static boolean aGoodBase (char c) {                
    char [] charArray = { 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T' };
    boolean aBase;

    if (c == 'A' || c == 'G' || c == 'C' || c == 'T') 
    {
       System.out.println(aBase);
       return true;     

    } 
    else 
    {
      System.out.println(aBase);      
      return false;

    }

  }  
}
```

Comment: You never initialize `aBase` before it's passed to `println` here.